# Do we call this picture "a sample" or "a model"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[image]

My daughter has to do a simple coloring task. She has to color the below picture and make it look exactly the above smaller picture.

Do we call the smaller picture "**a sample**" or "**a model**"?

For example, "**you have to copy coloring the above sample/model**"

Comment: Is the choice restricted to those two? I'd say "example" was better than either of them.

Comment: In a book designed for very small children, if we had to say something, we'd probably just say something like 'Colour in kitty'. The context being a colouring book, where the objective is to colour an outline image, sometimes with an example, sometimes not, the task will, in any event, be obvious. _My opinion_: Why overload a small child with language way beyond its needs at that stage of its life? Forcing children can have many bad consequences. (Note: substitute 'color' for 'colour' where appropriate).

Comment: Why 'exactly'? What happened to creativity? Personally, I'd find a picture _not_ exactly like the original, and the child who produced it, more interesting. Or diagnostic of colour blindness as with my son.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it's a model, but it's unnatural to use that word in a context like a children's colouring book. One natural way to say it:

> Colour this picture so it looks like *the original*."

"Model" has several meanings, but in this context, a model is *the example* you have to follow to complete something correctly. There is only one correct model.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/model):

> **7 :** a person or thing that serves as a pattern for an artist

A sample, on the other hand, is just *an example* of something to give an impression of what it's like. Its purpose is to give information about something, not so anyone can copy it. In this context, a sample would mean one possible way the child could colour the picture, but not the definitive way the child is expected to colour it. There could be several different samples to give an idea of different ways to colour the picture.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sample):

> **1 :** a representative part or a single item from a larger whole or group